# Can a class implementing a dictionary interface offer mapFile['inner']['outer'] syntax?

Tags: python

Can a Python class implement a dictionary interface (`__setitem__`, etc.) such that it supports the syntax:

```
mapFile['outer']['inner'] = 'value'
```

as if there were nested dictionaries? The class will be used as a read-write interface over a file on disk that has a key-value structure.

As a simple example, if the file on disk has keys/values of:

```
'a' = '1'
'b' = '2'
'c/d' = '3'
'c/e' = '4'
```

then the class could do

```
>> mapFile['c']['d']
'3'
>> mapFile['b']
'2'
>> mapFile['c']['d'] = '5'
>> mapFile['c']['d']
'5'
```

one way is to change the syntax to instead be:

```
mapFile['c', 'd'] = '5'
```

however, that is not the desired syntax because it passes a tuple into `__setitem__`.

Comment: Why not use [`collections.defaultdict(lambda: dict)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Comment: Why the restriction to a *single* class?

Comment: This is implementing a dict interface to a file on disk.

Comment: And more correct question (if I understand correctly) would be if `__setitem__` can take 2 indices. The fact that you want to use I for a dictionary seems beyond the question. I'm sure it's quite possible to have Map/Dictionary that has 2 keys.

Comment: You can also consider alternative syntax - how about `mapClass['outer', 'inner'] = 'value'`?

Comment: Part of the idea would be to avoid doing mapClass['outter/inner'] and then doing string operations to split it. If the split strings are known beforehand, I'd prefer not to waste the cycles.

Comment: @GregSmethells re-read my comment, it's two separate strings; you don't have to split the string, `__setitem__` can take tuples (or slice objects).

Comment: I was hoping for a prettier syntax that ```mapClass[('a', 'b')]```, but if ```__setitem__``` can handle as ```mapClass['outter', 'inner']```, then perhaps that is the preferred solution.

Comment: Long story short: the answer is trivially *"yes, there are various ways of doing that"*. But this isn't a code-writing service; where's your attempt?

Comment: @jonrsharpe My main point is that it's not `__index__` but `__setitem__`

Comment: Yes, I started with the wrong terminology. What is this then, attr? slicing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: FWIW, `defaultdict(dict)` is enough, no need for `lambda`.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini yes, I realised that too late to edit it; not sure what I was thinking!

Comment: Note that there were a few issues in your attempted code - for example, you should be using `isinstance` rather than `type`.

Comment: I disagree, and besides, the ```type()``` format is faster:  ```>>> timeit.timeit('type([]) in (tuple, list)', number = 10000)
0.0030601024627685547
>>> timeit.timeit('type([]) in (tuple, list)', number = 10000)
0.0032460689544677734
>>> timeit.timeit('isinstance([], (tuple, list))', number = 10000)
0.004960060119628906
>>> timeit.timeit('isinstance([], (tuple, list))', number = 10000)
0.0049610137939453125```

Comment: And you deleted the attempt after asking for it. Well played.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes because you can return anything from `__getitem__()`, including a *dict-like* object:

As a trivial example with a BIG deficiency (see below):

```
import dbm    

class NameBasedDbm(object):
    def __init__(self):    
        self.__open_files = {}    

    def __getitem__(self, filename):    
        db = self.__open_files.get(filename)    
        if not db:    
            db = dbm.open(filename, 'c')    
            self.__open_files[filename] = db    

        return db    


db = NameBasedDbm()    
db['test.db']['a'] = '1'    

print db['test.db']['a']
```

**WARNING** This is an demonstrative example only, don't (and I mean it) use this in any serious program, because it opens files and never closes them.

Doing it properly requires to know more about acceptable usage, e.g. how long it is okay to keep files open or if the performance hit of re-opening the file for any dictionary access is acceptable as well information about required thread-safety.

Comment: So, is the idiom to use ```__getitem__``` to handle the first evaluation and then return something that can be passed back into ```__setitem__```. Perhaps, it would be best to store the key thus far and return self in order to recurse.

Comment: You only need to override `__setitem__` on the outer class when you want to support assignments of the form `db['test.db'] = foo`, the `db[0]{1]` never uses `__setitem__` on the outer dictionary-like. The inner dict like needs to support item assigment, though.

Comment: Actually both args are part of the full key. Neither are filenames.